# Angular 2 - Make multiple HTTP get request based on different context at same time?

Tags: angular, angular-http

My REST call service have different url context to get different data's. I would like to make a HTTP get request at the sametime and map the response to the three different dropdown's.

My code:

```
protected getCodes1(): string {
        const apiConfig = 'http://www.example.com/context1'; (need to change the context based on parameter)
        if (!uri) {
            throw new Error('Missing API);
        }
        return uri;
 }
 protected getCodes2(): string {
        const apiConfig = 'http://www.example.com/context2'; (need to change the context based on parameter)
        if (!uri) {
            throw new Error('Missing API);
        }
        return uri;
 }
 protected getCodes3(): string {
        const apiConfig = 'http://www.example.com/context3'; (need to change the context based on parameter)
        if (!uri) {
            throw new Error('Missing API);
        }
        return uri;
 }
```

My HTTP Call:

```
const getCodesList1 = getCodes1();
const getCodesList2 = getCodes2();
const getCodesList3 = getCodes3();
this.http.get('getCodeList1'),
this.http.get('anotherurl'),
this.http.get('anotheranotherurl'),
(response1, response2, response3) => {
    //do something to put them all together
    //return a single object
}
).subscibe(finalObject => ...)
```

I didn't get the response properly on it. Please give me a clue to get the stuff..Appreciate for some clue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `forkJoin` or `mergeMap` operators from `RxJS`

Example:

```
ngOnInit() {

    let character = this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1');
    let characterHomeworld = this.http.get('http://swapi.co/api/planets/1');

    forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe(results => {
      // results[0] is our character
      // results[1] is our character homeworld
      results[0].homeworld = results[1];
      this.loadedCharacter = results[0];
    });
  }
```